# Определение ориентации страницы на фотографии

Tags: java

Каким образом можно определить находится ли страница с текстом в правильной книжной ориентации (не перевернута) не используя распознавание текста?

На странице нет каких-то ориентиров по которым можно было бы это отслеживать (номера страницы внизу и т.п.), текст не следует какому то определенному шаблону форматирования.

Comment: А если не на текст, то на что ещё вы хотите ориентироваться? Можно пытаться распознать конкретные знаки буквы (по которым будет понятно что лист перевёрнут: Аа Ее Сс Тт например ). Можно пытаться распознать точки запятые и "рядочек", и по "рядочку" и знакам препинания пытаться сделать такой вывод.

Comment: Есть алгоритмы для распознавания. Либо в гугл, либо костыль можно самому написать. Принцип примерно таков: проволим линии по вертикали и горизонтали по всей странице. Для каждой линии считаем сколько пикселей под ней черные, а сколько белые. В тех что будут идти паралельно рядкам будут наблюдаться очень контрастные линии, где в олной много черного, а в другой много белого. В перпендикулярных все линии будут примерно в среднем серые. Ищите готовый алгоритм. Очень много "но"